# Массив с полученными данными из CoreData превращается в nil

Tags: ios, swift, coredata

Есть массив `var messages: [Message]?` в котором хранится информация из CoreData. Загрузить информацию в массив и заполнить tableView у меня получилось, информация в массиве есть(от туда я ее и брал для заполнения tableView), но при обращении к массиву из метода didSelectRowAt все элементы выводятся nil(в том числе и сущность).

Вывод элементов массива из viewDidLoad

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод элементов массива из didSelectRowAt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Честно говоря, даже не могу предположить, почему так происходит, тк изменение массива не происходит, после заполнения. Прикладываю код этого контроллера.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

class MainTVC: UITableViewController {

    var messages: [Message]?
    private let managedObjectContext = CoreDataStack().managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("WOWOWOOWOWOWOOWOWO")
        let friends = fetchFriends()
        guard friends != nil else {return}
        let names = deleteDuplicateNames(array: friends!)
        messages = [Message]()
        print(names.count)
        for name in names {
            fetchMsg(name: name)
        }
        messages = messages?.sorted(by: {$0.date?.compare($1.date! as Date) == .orderedDescending})
        print("in viewDidLoad")
        for message in messages! {
            print(message as Message)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = messages?.count {
            return count
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell

        let message = messages![indexPath.row]

        cell.msgLabel.text = message.text
        cell.nameLabel.text = message.friend?.name
        cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: message.friend?.profileImageName ?? "none")
        if message.date != nil {
            cell.dateLabel.text = getFormattedDate(date: message.date!)
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(messages![indexPath.row])
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("in didSelectRowAt")
        for message in messages! {
            print(message as Message)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "newUser" {
            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let newTaskController = navigationController.topViewController as! CreateNewUserVC

            newTaskController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        }

    }


    func getFormattedDate(date: NSDate) -> String {

        let dateForm = DateFormatter()
        dateForm.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

        return dateForm.string(from: date as Date)

    }

    func fetchFriends() -> [Friend]? {
        let req = NSFetchRequest<Friend>(entityName: "Friend")

        do {
            return try CoreDataStack().managedObjectContext.fetch(req) as [Friend]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func deleteDuplicateNames(array: [Friend]) -> [String] {
        var names = [String]()
        for element in array {
            names.append(element.name!)
        }
        return Array(Set(names))
    }

    func fetchMsg(name: String) {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", name)
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

        do {
            let fetchedMsg = try CoreDataStack().managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as [Message]
            //print("Msg from \(friend.name!): \(fetchedMsg.first?.text!)")
            messages?.append(contentsOf: fetchedMsg)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно у вас получилось. Попробуйте вывести отдельно поля класса message, там тоже null будет?

Comment: Да, я пытался выводить по-разному, nil пишет. Думал проблема в контексте, но у меня он не изменяется.

Comment: Можете попробовать сделать так: создаете промежуточную модель, в которую записываете данные из CoreData (пишите конвертер из класса message в эту модель), создаете коллекцию из элементов этой модели (а не модели CoreData). И пишете метод, который будет слушать изменения в CoreData, при изменениях обновляете коллекцию с промежуточной моделью. Потом проверяете, смотрите где вызывается метод на обновление.